# Percentage of unanswered questions (bug?)

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, stats

I thought I would have a look at the unanswered questions on JSE, so I went to:

```
questions?sort=unanswered
```

And according to the results, it says there are **91** questions. However, when I do a "find" action in the browser for `0 answers`, there are 28 matches in total.

I then has a look at the JSE stats on Area51 and apparently only **85%** of questions had been answered.

So if the **correct** results for unanswered question is **28**, how is this **15%** of the total questions asked on JSE (619 so far)?

Is this a bug, or do questions have to have more than 1 answer to be considered an "answered" question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We unfortunately use two different definitions of "unanswered" depending on which page you're looking at - one is "no answers at all" and the other is "no upvoted answers".

The tooltip on the "unanswered" tab you're looking at notes that we're using the latter definition there:

> Questions that have no upvoted answers

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up Anna

Comment: Thanks for the info. One quick additional question: Does a question count as answered if an answer has X upvotes, or does it have to be marked as "Accepted" to count as answered in the statistics?

Comment: @johanpw It doesn't have to be marked as accepted.